# How to read nth line and mth field of text file in unix

Tags: unix, sed, cut

Suppose i have | delimeted file,

```
Line1:    1|2|3|4
Line2:    5|6|7|8
Line3:    9|9|1|0
```

Now i need to read 3 field at second line which is 7 in above example how i can do that using Cut or Sed Command. I'm new to unix please help

Comment: you can use awk to achieve that

Comment: You'll need to read the file sequentially. Maybe you want to use some database e.g. [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) instead

Comment: You could also use `sed` with `cut` but you need to **read the documentation** of [sed(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) and of [cut(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)

Comment: `sed -n '2p' file.txt | cut -d'|' -f 3`

Comment: or `sed '2!d' file.txt | cut -d'|' -f 3`

Answer (score 3):

A job for `awk`:

```
awk -F '|' 'NR==2{print $3}' file
```

or

```
awk -F '|' -v row=2 -v col=3 'NR==row{print $col}' file
```

Output:

```
7
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`sed -n '2p' file |awk -F '|' '{print $3}'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -rn '2s/^(([^|]*)\|?){3}.*/\2/p' file
```

Turn off automatic printing by setting the `-n` option, turn on easier regexp declaration by `-r` option. Use pattern matching and back references to replace the whole of the second line by the third field of the same line and print the result.

The address of the substitution command is limited to only the second line.

The regexp groups the non-delimited characters followed by a delimiter a specific number of times. The second group, only retains the non-delimited characters for the specific number. Each grouping is replaced by the next and so the last grouping is reported, the `.*` consumes the remainder of the line and so only the third field  (contents of second group) is printed.

N.B. the delimiter would be present following the final column and is therefore optional `\|?`